# Safety using entity from different part of program

Tags: c++, singleton, software-design

I have several modules in my program (e.g. Database, Scheduler) which uses same entity - some game server.

Main goal is that each module uses game server API with limited functionality (functionality which need for interaction between separate module and game server only) and other functions must be hide.

I have created such functionality. But I don't now, maybe it's wrong realization or maybe somebody guess better method.

Class which placed below contain some operations which can be access only from others modules via classes wrappers.

```
#ifndef _GAMESERVER_
#define _GAMESERVER_

#include <vector>

class GameServer
{
        static GameServer instance;
        std::vector<int> game_actions;
        GameServer(){}
        ~GameServer(){}
        GameServer(const GameServer&){}

protected:
        void addGameAction(int action) // Some functionality, which can be accessible     only from others modules via classes wrapers
        {
                game_actions.push_back(action);
        }

public:
        static GameServer *getInstance()
        {
                return &instance;
        }
        bool start()
        {
                return true;
        }
        void stop()
        {
        }
};
#endif
```

Below placed class 'wrapper' for class GameServer which has been realising API for interaction with module Database.

```
#ifndef _DBGAMESERVER_
#define _DBGAMESERVER_

/* Database module will use this API for interacting with game server */

class GameServer;

class DBGameServer : protected GameServer
{
        DBGameServer();

 public:
        static DBGameServer *getInstance()
        {
                return static_cast<DBGameServer *>(GameServer::getInstance());
        }
        void addGameAction(int action)
        {
                GameServer::addGameAction(action);
        }
};
#endif
```

Thanks!

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<DBGameServer *>` should be a `static_cast`. But seriously, it's completely unclear for me, what you want to achieve with the _wrapper_. Why not use abstract interfaces instead, and expose these to the modules, that should use them?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<DBGameServer*>` is bad: the object created by `getInstance()` is `GameServer`, not `DBGameServer`. Also, some potential errors: 1) someone calls `stop()`, and after that someone uses the singleton; 2) getInstance is not thread-safe.

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: @MrMush I want to have one entity which will be safety used from different part of the program for example: database module hasn't permits for calling GameServer::stop () that why I have created separate class DBGameServer, which hasn't operation stop() so it can safety uses with DB module.

Comment: @Inspired 1) Method stop() is accessible only from GameServer class, and from classes 'wrappers' this operation isn't accessible because i'm using protected inheritance between classes 'wrappers' and GameServer, so stop() could call only from one place (from function main()).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your singleton instance at first call to `getIntance`. It may be unsafe in a multithreaded application : race conditions could lead to multiple instances being actually intialized and used.

IMHO you would better use static initialization :

Declaration :

```
...
class GameServer {
    static GameServer& instance;
    // private constructor, copie constructor and destructor
    ...
public:
    static GameServer * getInstance() { return &instance; }
    ...
}
```

Implementation :

```
...
GameServer & GameServer::instance = GameServer();
...
```

That way you are sure that the object is constructed only once during program start (before first instruction), and destructor is called at program end (after last instruction). Of course if constructor throws an exception the program will stop abruptly  before it is given any chance to display anything : the eventual error messages should be displayed inside constructor.